# Passing non-static member function as parameter of function

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to pass a non-static member function to a parameter

```
class Foo {
    void f() {}
    void caller() {
        //calling of g() happens here using f()
    }
};

Class Goo {
    std::map<int,std::vector<std::function<void()>>>> m;
    void g(int i, std::function<void()> const& h) {
        m[i].push_back(h);
    }
}
```

I tried calling 
`g(f), g(Foo::f), g(std::make_fn(Foo::f), g(std::make_fn(Foo:f, this), g(this.f)`
and also also tried to pass it as reference (althought it should ).
The error i get is of invalid use of nonstatic member function.

Edit: I added the functionality behind `g()`

Comment: Please note that you can't store references in containers. If you want references, then use pointers instead. In this case, it doesn't make sense; just store values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have to solve is that `this` argument is implicit for non-static member function. This means that if you want to call the member function later you need to pass pointer to the object as well.

One of the ways to do this is to use `std::bind(&Foo::f, this)`

**Update 1**
You can use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to tie lifetime of `Foo` to the lifetime of a functor that is created by the `std::bind`.

```
class Foo : std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
    void f() {}
    void caller() {
        // CAVEAT! shared_from_this() will work iff instance of `Foo` is already owned 
        // by an std::shared_ptr. This means that when you create `Foo`
        // you must do so via std::make_shared<Foo>()
        g(std::bind(&Foo::f, shared_from_this()));
    }
};
```

This is how you can bind lifetime of Foo to the lifetime of the `std::function` that is produced via `std::bind`.

Please see the caveat in the code comment though.

**Update 2** 
Your functor vector is incorrect.

```
std::map<int,std::vector<std::function<void()>const&>> m;
```

must be

```
std::map<int,std::vector<std::function<void()>>> m;
```

(without const reference)

Comment: This solution gave me an entirely new set of errors. The g() actually takes the functions and pushes them into a vector where it stores them to be executed late. It gave me errors about forming reference type and allocator error

Comment: @ZergOvermind What are you trying to acheive by that?

Comment: Those functions are supposed to be executed whenever given event happens. `g()` represents the subscribe function and `f()` is supposed to be the function that for that given object does something with whatever data it will recieve or it will simply record the fact that the event happened. To be more specific i store map of vectors of function where every event has corespinding vector of functions which it then executes.

Comment: I added it to the `g()`

Comment: @ZergOvermind there is a solution that involves binding a smart pointer (`std::shared_ptr` to be precise) instead of `this`. This will make sure that the instance of `Foo` is alive so that the function can be executed correctly. But this solution requires `Foo` to already be under `std::shared_ptr` ownership, which may or may not feel clumsy, depending on the rest of your architecture.

Comment: It is an assignment which will be tested by automated tests so i don't think i can expected that.

Comment: @ZergOvermind see my update then. However, StackOverflow can not help you with assignments, pretty sure it was against some rule...

Comment: To be fair, quite a huge part of stack overflow is helping with assignments. I;m not asking for anyone to do my work for me, just looking for answers.

Comment: I think i actually just got confused by the error. The bind was the solution but the next errors (icluded in edit) are from map because it cant store references to functions (might be wrong tho).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drily passing the function address and hope for correct casts, you can use type-safe [Functor](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html) pattern to pass functions as arguments.

I.e. declare a class for function *f()* and put the implementation in *operator()*. You can use the constructor to preload any kind of function argument, or use the arguments of an overloaded *operator()*. You can pass the function around like an object, cache values as long as you like, and dispose of any memory when you do no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize lamba to wrap up a member function call:

```
void g(std::function<void()> const&);

class Foo
{
    void f(void) {}

    void caller(void)
    {
        g
        (
             ::std::function<void (void)>
             {
                  // we need to capture "this" because f is a non-static member function
                  [this](void) -> void
                  {
                      f();
                  }
              }
         );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind function with this using std::bind

> g( std::bind(&Foo::f, this) );

Here full solution:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
void g(std::function<void()> const& func){
        func();
};
class Foo {
public:
    void f() const{std::cout<<"function f()\n";}
    void caller() const {
        //calling of g() happens here using f()
        g( std::bind(&Foo::f, this) );
    }
};
```